# PowerShell to move file type up one dir

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm looking for a script the moves a certain file type *.msg up one directory but still remaining their project ID folder.

The current file structure looks like:

```
Host Folder\C12345678\A\test.msg
Host Folder\C12345678\B\test.msg
Host Folder\C99999999\F\test.msg
Host Folder\C56351114\T\test.msg
Host Folder\C69365814\I\test.msg
```

I want to remove the lettering, so just the project ID hosts the *.msg:

```
Host Folder\C12345678\test(A).msg
Host Folder\C12345678\test(B).msg
Host Folder\C99999999\test.msg
Host Folder\C56351114\test.msg
Host Folder\C69365814\test.msg
```

Currently, my code is just moving the various *.msg file to the Host folder, unable to duplicate folders.

```
$src = "..\Host Folder"

$files = Get-ChildItem $src -file -recurse 
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        #Move-Item $file.PSPath $src
    }
```

I mostly batch file so I'm not so good with PS but I need to add $src\$files?

Comment: All of the code you've posted so far is powershell, not batch. That doesn't really match the title of your question.

Comment: fair point sorry I've attempted this both in batch and PS, I shall rename, originally I was trying with Robo copy when I started this post.

Comment: Have you tried the search function here or, google? Lots of similar questions have been asked already. Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Move+files+up+one+directory+%5Bpowershell%5D) and see if any of those are helpful.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala yes, I've been through a little bit now and a couple of different methods trying to hodgepodge something together. I'll keep working away

Comment: Why do the first two items in your desired output have the original parent foldername in brackets (`test(A).msg`) and the others don't ?

Comment: @theo because there's potential for other folders in the directory to house duplicate named files, I haven't even got to script that part yet though.